# Multiple-Account Contacts vs Duplicate Contacts

Tags: accountcontactrelation

I have a client who wants to support [multiple accounts per contact](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=shared_contacts_overview.htm&type=5) (right now the contacts are just duplicated for multiple accounts)

While salesforce supports this feature out of the box, I have major concerns on the impact of enabling this feature.

Seems like it would make it much more challenging to add automation around the contact as you [lose the ability to do a lot of stuff out of the box](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=shared_contacts_considerations.htm&type=5).  Instead old and new functionality will have to be developed via apex, greatly increasing cost of development and maintenance.

If you use both the "Direct" & "Indirect" relationships, the you basically have to develop everything twice.  If you only support "Indirect" relationships, then you likely need to reimplement a lot of out of the box stuff (which you'd probably need to also do with the former approach).

My leaning towards recommending that they stay on the "duplicate contact per account" path.

Are my concerns warranted or overstated?  Anything else I should be considering?

Comment: personally having a single contact in a system per person is a foundational principle of a good CRM system as it allows a single view of the customer. having multiple identical contacts on different accounts can make it very difficult for salesforce users to get that single view of the customer and would likely require a lot of customization to support this effectively. yes, supporting multiple accounts adds effort, but no more than the current account contact role table that is getting replaced by the new functionality. in terms of automation, by default just support direct

Comment: @RalphCallaway Assuming that was the approach they took from the start, I would have to agree.  However, I think you've understated the challenges in such a transition.  I don't see how you could get by only supporting "Direct" relationships via automation, unless the nature of the contact is that it has a "primary" account (which it doesn't in this case).  There's also concerns impact with integrations/packages may only support the direct relationships

Comment: The situation seems fairly analogous to what you get with Affiliations out of the box with the Nonprofit Success Pack. I've never been in a situation where many of the costs of that architecture "hurt"; the biggest issue I've seen is that that level of indirection can make reporting rather more challenging, and you tend to need something like DLRS (or a lot of custom Apex) to get the level of summary info about relationships that users want.